# Actualizar componentes en java

Tags: java

Estoy actualizando una aplicacion desarrollada por unos compañeros hace ya unos años. Pero me sale este error. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

> Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\enterprise
>
> Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ide
>
> Scanning for modules in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform
>
> Scanning for modules in suite D:\SCHOOL\CLASES\TESIS\APLICACION\Zera1.X-unstable_MatSim
>
> warning: had to upgrade dependencies for module zera.matsim.interaccion: added = [module org.netbeans.api.progress.compat8 > 1.40, module org.openide.filesystems.nb, module org.openide.filesystems.compat8] removed = []; details: [Separation of desktop and cleanup, Swing dependencies split away]
> C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\harness\build.xml:174: Cannot compile against a module: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\enterprise\modules\org-netbeans-modules-websvc-restlib.jar because of dependency: org.netbeans.modules.websvc.restlib/0-1 > 1.16.1 found 1.0.1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tienes que resolver las dependencias de los módulos que te indica el compilador.
Leyendo un poco por encima veo que hay incluso alguno borrado. Busca los módulos por Internet y cambialos a la versión que te aconseja el compilador o una superior.

Comment: Esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta no? aunque correcto, lo reportaron como no es una respuesta. Te pareceria convertilo a comentario?

Comment: Bueno, pues debería buscarse la librería compat8 (superior a la 1.4), restlib con una versión superior a la 1.16. Te falla el build de la aplicación porque no encuentra los módulos anteriores.